# Load Tensorflow .pb file directly from memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have a .pb model file stored as bytes in Redis. I want to load this model directly using `tf.saved_model.load()` instead of saving to disk first, as the `load()` method expects a directory name. Is there any other way you can load .pb file directly from memory?